# What does it mean for a function to be $\Omega(1)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having a lot of trouble understanding this. Could someone put this in a context I might understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(n)=\Omega(g(n)) \text{ if there is a } n \in \mathbb{N}_0, c>0 \text{ such that: }$$

$$f(n) \geq c g(n)$$

In your case $g(n)=1$.

So there is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}_0, c>0$ such that $f(n) \geq c $, so the function is bounded below from a constant.